# Manipulating similar objects in a form using another form

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I want to utilize the forms with one another.

I have 2 forms. (1)MMCMLibrary_home and (2)MMCMLibrary_reserve.

In this project, I'm in the stage of changing the label background colors in Form 1 but can't seem to utilize Form 2 to process it.

These are my necessary codes so far:

**FORM 1**
[image]

```
namespace MMCM_Library
{
    public partial class MMCMLibrary_home : Form
    {
        public static MMCMLibrary_home instance;

        //DCR1 Labels
        public Label lbl1_1;
        public Label lbl1_2;
        public Label lbl1_3;
        public Label lbl1_4;
        public MMCMLibrary_home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            instance = this;
            lbl1_1 = lblDCR1_9;
            lbl1_2 = lblDCR2_11;
            lbl1_3 = lblDCR1_1;
            lbl1_4 = lblDCR1_3;

 public void btnDCR1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var reserveDCR1 = new MMCMLibrary_reserve();
            reserveDCR1.Show();
             
        }

        public void btnDCR2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var reserveDCR2 = new MMCMLibrary_reserve();
            reserveDCR2.Show();
        }

        public void btnDCR3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var reserveDCR3 = new MMCMLibrary_reserve();
            reserveDCR3.Show();
        }


        public void btnDCR4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var reserveDCR4 = new MMCMLibrary_reserve();
            reserveDCR4.Show();
        }

       
    }
}
```

**FORM 2**

when I click any reserve now button in form 1 it will open form 2. However, if I pick a radio button, the background change will always be applied to Discussion Room 1 even I reserved for discussion room 2
[image]

```
namespace MMCM_Library
{
    public partial class MMCMLibrary_reserve : Form
    {
        public static MMCMLibrary_reserve instance;




        public MMCMLibrary_reserve()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            instance = this;
        }

        private void MMCMLibrary_reserve_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void splitContainer1_Panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void splitContainer1_Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

       
        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnDCR1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void btnDCRoomsReserve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (rbtn9.Checked)
            {
               MMCMLibrary_home.instance.lbl1_1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Can you help me to device an efficient way to solve this. Can you also suggest a database method suitable for my beginner project.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said that:

> the background change will always be applied to Discussion Room 1

Well, yes. It seems you don't pass specific object into Form2. There's strightforward:

```
MMCMLibrary_home.instance.lbl1_1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

So you'll be always changing backcolor of lbl1_1 of your Form1. What needs to be done is to indicate which room has been selected. You can assign room after you click the button by passing the int parameter:

```
public void btnDCR1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var reserveDCR1 = new MMCMLibrary_reserve(1);
   reserveDCR1.Show();          
}
```

or:

```
public void btnDCR2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var reserveDCR2 = new MMCMLibrary_reserve(2);
   reserveDCR2.Show();
}
```

Then, in Form2, at the very top, add something like:
int room; to be able to assign the room number in Form2:

```
public MMCMLibrary_reserve(int roomNumber)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   room = roomNumber;
   instance = this;
}
```

And then you could just select room you clicked, by:

```
public void btnDCRoomsReserve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (rbtn9.Checked)
   {
      if(room == 1)
      {
         MMCMLibrary_home.instance.lbl1_1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
      }
      else if(room == 2)
      {
         MMCMLibrary_home.instance.lbl1_2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
      }
      else if(room == 3)
      {
         MMCMLibrary_home.instance.lbl1_3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
      }
      else if(room == 4)
      {
         MMCMLibrary_home.instance.lbl1_4.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
      }
  }
  else if(radioButton2.Checked)
  {
      //etc.
  }
  else if(radioButton3.Checked)
  {
      //etc.
  }
  else if(radioButton4.Checked)
  {
      //etc.
  }
```

}

I think that was the problem. Try it and let us know.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just used lbl1_1, lbl2_1, lbl3_1, ... on the first rbtn9 if statement and it works.